# Run functions only in the admin area?

Tags: functions, admin-menu

I'd like this code to only run inside the admin area as it is resorting the items on the public side admin bar too.

```
  /* Reorder Admin Menu to put "Pages" at the top */
  function menu_order_filter($menu) {
  $content_menu = array('edit.php?post_type=page');
  array_splice($menu, 2, 0, $content_menu);
  return array_unique($menu);
  }
  add_filter('custom_menu_order', create_function('', 'return true;'));
  add_filter('menu_order', 'menu_order_filter');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is very little overhead to assigning couple of filters on hooks that simply won't fire on front end.

In general it would be something like this:

```
add_action('init', 'admin_only');

function admin_only() {

    if( !is_admin() )
        return;

    // filter assignemnts and such go here
}
```

Also `create_function()` is not recommended for performance and some other reasons. It is better to use more modern [Anonymous Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), but for cases like this WordPress provides ready-made `__return_true()` function.

Comment: Sorry i'm more of a copy/paste hacker at the moment. How would i modify my above code to use __return_true()? Thanks.

Comment: @firefusion simply replace `create_function('', 'return true;')` with `'__return_true'`

Comment: You could just hook onto `admin_init` instead of `init` and you'll not need that `is_admin()` check.

Comment: @t31os yep - that will work too. I just usually have giant wrapper running on init and it is more convenient to keep both admin and non-admin stuff in there.

Comment: anonymous functions only work in PHP 5.3+. I'd be curious to know more about the disadvantages of create_function

Comment: @AmbitiousAmoeba as far as I remember function is generated with randomized name and is harmful for opcode caching (APC, eAccelerator and such)

Comment: Funny, the docs say upwards of version 4.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

Comment: @t31os `create_function()` and Anonymous Functions (aka Closures) are different things. Latter are recent addition indeed.

Comment: My bad, didn't notice the link before.. :-s

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
     echo "You are viewing the theme";
} else {
     echo "You are viewing the WordPress Administration Panels";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the Hook admin_init and later hooks, the init-Hook comes realy ealier as only the admin. But it is important, when you use li18n-functions or AJAX, than it is better you use init.

Answer (score 0):

**Update in 2020**, Working answer, I went to different answers none of them works now in new WordPress.

```
function hide_categories_for_specific_user( $exclusions, $args ){

if ( ((defined( 'REST_REQUEST' ) && REST_REQUEST) or $GLOBALS['pagenow'] === 'edit.php' ) && !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {

   // IDs of terms to be excluded
   $exclude_array = array("12","16","17"); // CHANGE THIS TO IDs OF YOUR TERMS


   // Generation of exclusion SQL code
   $exterms = wp_parse_id_list( $exclude_array );
   foreach ( $exterms as $exterm ) {
           if ( empty($exclusions) )
               $exclusions = ' AND ( t.term_id <> ' . intval($exterm) . ' ';
       else
               $exclusions .= ' AND t.term_id <> ' . intval($exterm) . ' ';
   }

   // Closing bracket
   if ( !empty($exclusions) )
   $exclusions .= ')';

   // Return our SQL statement

  }
   return $exclusions;
}

 // Finally hook up our filter
 add_filter( 'list_terms_exclusions', 'hide_categories_for_specific_user', 10, 2 );
```

answer final help from [Hide Some Categories in Post Editor](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hide-some-categories-in-post-editor/)